# Access variable in require'd ruby code

Tags: ruby

What's the scope of a variable in a piece of code that has been `require`'d?

e.g. say I have a piece of code like this in a file called `users.rb`:

```
users = ...
```

and this line is not in a class or in a method. I then `require` this file. E.g. in `app.rb`

```
require './users.rb'
```

What's the scope of that variable (`users`) and how would I access it?

Answer (score 1):

Variables which start with a lower case letter are *local variables*. Local variables are called local variables because they are local to the scope they are defined in and cannot be accessed from a different scope.

> What's the scope of a variable in a piece of code that has been `require`'d?

In your particular case, the scope is the script body of `users.rb`.

> how would I access it?

You can't. That's the whole purpose of local variables.